# Apache Camel Ftp2 order of downloaded files

Tags: java, apache-camel

How I can specify the order in which I want to pull data from ftp, for instance for some folders I want to pull data in alphabetical order or numerical but for another I need to sort out it by some complex expression (parse data, define quarter and sort them out by querter) is there a way to create a sorter (filter) which will give us this flexibility?

Answer (score 3):

The FTP component uses the same sorting options as the File component. So check its wiki page
http://camel.apache.org/file2

For example you can use a custom sorter. See the option table for more details.

See this unit test
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/FileSorterRefTest.java

Comment: Does file consuming happens in sorting order? could not find that it written directly,

Comment: what is the default ordering?

Comment: There is no default sorting, its the order that the OS gives in the list of files using the API used by Camel.

Comment: does **sorting** means order of files consuming in case of sftp consumer?

Comment: I think you didn't notice my question in previous comment. Can you please give me answer ?

Comment: Yes if you configure sorting on the ftp endpoint then it consume the files in the sorted order

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen, what do you mean by the API used by Camel? How does the consumer knows if there are files still being copied to a directory? I assume that the consumer picks the files per arrival... meaning that there has to be a pre sort step.